# Concatenate random element from list with user input in Python

Tags: python, list, input

I'm writing a code that allows a user to enter a city they have been to. After the user inputs it, I want my code to return a randomly generated remark about the city from my list. However, whenever I run the code, it concatenates the user input with a random letter, which is not my intention of the code.

```
import random

message = "Type your city here: "

#Comments to concatenate with user input
comments = [f"what a lovely {}", f"I always wanted to visit {}", "I hope you enjoyed your trip to {}"]

#While loop for user input
while True:
   message = input(message)

   for elem in comments:
      message += random.choice(elem)

   if message == "quit":
      break
```

Comment: You can't use f-strings like that. You have to use `.format` on the concatenated string

Comment: Surely you want to check for `quit` before constructing the message.  You do not want the `f` prefix on those strings.  You destroy your prompt message the first time through the loop.  You don't need a `for` loop in there, just `print(random.choice(comments).format(message))`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what your looking for?

```
import random
#Comments to concatenate with user input 
comments = ["what a lovely ", "I always wanted to visit ", "I hope you enjoyed your trip to "]

#While loop for user input
message = None
while message != "quit":
   message = input("Type your city here: ")
   print(random.choice(comments)+message)
```

Comment: It will crash because the message is not defined in the while.

Comment: Thank you very much! The code runs exactly as intended. Edit: don't worry about the 'message' variable, I defined it. Much appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend coding a function that takes the city as input then at the end returns the list. Like this

```
def random_quote(city):
    comments = [f"what a lovely ", f"I always wanted to visit ", "I hope you 
     enjoyed your trip to "]
    comment = random.choice(comments)
    return comment + city
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice()` accepts a list (take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)), Don't iterate over your `comments` variable, pass it to `random.choice()` and don't forget to replace `{}` with the city:

```py
city = input('Please enter a city')

comment = random.choice(comments)

comment.replace('{}', city)

print(comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a for loop inside your while. You should always avoid `while True` as it is an opening for bugs. Having a `break` inside a loop usually marks bad programming.

You should probably read a bit about what `f-string` is before using it, you also don't seem to know what `random.choice` does since you put it into the for which gave it the messages, which it randomly took a character out of.

```
import random


def main():
    prompt = "Type your city here: "

    # Comments to concatenate with user input
    comments = ["what a lovely ", "I always wanted to visit ", "I hope you enjoyed your trip to "]

    usr_input = input(prompt)
    # While loop for user input
    while usr_input != 'quit':
        message = random.choice(comments) + usr_input
        usr_input = input(prompt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```